# how to make the in-line math equation as shown in the figure beautifully arranged in text?

Tags: spacing, equations, inline, text

[image]

When discussing and explaining some math equations,  I sometimes prefer to use in-line equations (created by use $ ... $ in the text) in the text environment, as shown ONLY in the last two lines.

However, you have seen that the long in-line equation

```
$f(x_i,\eta_i,m)=|x_i|+\log(\frac{2}{\eta_i})(\frac{|x_i|}{3mp_i}+|x_i|\sqrt{(\frac{1}{3mp_i})^2+\frac{2}{\log(2/\eta_i)}(\frac{1}{mp_i}-\frac{1}{m})})$
```

is ugly arranged in text, with very big space. Do you have any method to  let this in-line equation (automatically) have a norm space between each term, and at the same time, the extra part of this long equation can (automatically) start from the next line? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If inline math takes more than one line, use display math.  Note \shortintertext from mathtools.

Answer (score 2):

Not using inline math here would be the normal advice!

Or set the sentence in a `\raggedright` (or `\begin{flushleft}`) as that is what you want it to do: allow lines to be short without stretching them to fit.